# same eigenvalues gives addition of eigenvectors being an eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over $ \Bbb C$, and let $T \in L(V )$.

Let v be an eigenvector for T
with eigenvalue $ \lambda $, and let $w \in V $ be an eigenvector for T with eigenvalue $\mu $, and suppose that $ v \neq -w $.
Prove that $v + w$ is an eigenvector for T if and only if $ \lambda = \mu $

I understand the condition that $ v \neq -w $. but there is something fundamental missing for my understanding of eigenvalues why is it that $v + w$ is not an eigenvector? i mean if $\lambda, \mu $ are the same then $v+w$ points in the same direction of v or of w (possibly they both point in the same direction) but if not i see no reason why $v+w$ isnt an eigenvector?

Comment: $v+w$ does not necessarily point in the same direction as $v$ or $w$.

Comment: is that because we are over $\Bbb C $ or would it be the same case over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: $v=(1,0)$ and $w=(0,1)$ are both eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1 for the identity matrix, and their sum doesn't point in the same direction as either of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is $\;\alpha\in\Bbb C\;$ s.t.

$$\alpha(v+w)=T(v+w)=Tv+Tw=\lambda v+\mu w\implies (\alpha-\lambda)v=-(\alpha-\mu)w$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: what you've written down is simple enough but i cant seem to glean why your doing it or what it means :(

Comment: Literally all that comes to mind  is hey look complex conjugate?

Comment: Who or what looks like complex conjugate? You have$$(\alpha-\lambda)v+(\alpha-\mu)w=0$$If one of the two scalars is non zero, then $\;v,\,w\;$ are linearly *dependent*, which means of of them is a multiple scalar of the other one and thus they both are eigenvectors of **the same eigenvalue** and thus we're done. Otherwise... **what** ?

Comment: Sorry i understand your argument now the far right looked like complex conjugate to me but im just crazy.

Comment: @Faust You say in your profile you have lots of problems with your English...aren't you in Victoria, Australia?

Comment: I am actually from Victoria BC Canada (the british weren't so original naming things) It's not something id really like to post on the internet; suffice it to say my brain doesn't work the way its supposed to but English is my native language.

Comment: @Faust Oh, I see. Good luck.